# Use wireless mouse with laptop

Tags: laptop, wireless-networking, mouse

Is it possible to use a wireless mouse for a laptop, and if so, how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to purchase either a wireless mouse with a USB receiver, or a bluetooth capable mouse if your laptop is so equipped.

Either situation should be pretty much plug-and play.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.

You just need to plug the receiver into one of the laptop's USB ports.

If your laptop has built in Bluetooth support you can get [a mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=099) which won't need an external receiver.